# From PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, android, sqlite, pdo

I have the following code on my PHP webapp, it uses PHP to look for products in a Sqlite3 Databse file locally. I was tryng to convert it into an Android App with Phonegap, but sadly Phonegap does't work with PHP, so I thought I could make a JavaScript file replacing the PHP.

However, I can't get it to work. In case what I am trying to do is impossible, I guess there should be a way to execute the PHP files on the server and just display the results on the app.

```
($_GET['busq']){
    $busq=$_GET['busq'];

    function ultlet($cadena) {
       $cant = strlen($cadena);
       $cant--;
       $let = substr($cadena, $cant);
       if ($let == "s") {
          $cadena = substr($cadena, 0, $cant);   
       } 
       return $cadena;
    }

    str_replace("-",$busq," ");
    $arreg=explode(" ",$busq);
    $cuent=count($arreg);

    for($a=0;$a<$cuent;$a++){
       $arreg[$a] = ultlet($arreg[$a]); 
    }
    $query="SELECT * from MyTable WHERE";

    for($i=0;$i<$cuent;$i++){
        if ($i>=1){
            $query=$query." AND ";
        }
        $query=$query." (col1 LIKE \"%$arreg[$i]%\"   OR col6 LIKE \"%$arreg[$i]%\") ";
    }

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:MyDatabase.sqlite');
    $result = $db->query($query);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if ($row['codigo_cat']!=null){
            $class = 'class="image"';
        }else{
            $class = 'class="row"';
        }
        echo '<div '.$class.' alt="'.$row['col4'].'">';
        echo 'Codigo: '.$row['col2']." / ".$row['col3']."<br>";
        echo 'Nombre: '.$row['col1']."<br>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

There is also another file wich based on the user's input on a search bar creates the variable 'busq' which is used to display the products and its prices.

Comment: Your code excerpt is not complete. `($_GET['busq']){` makes no sense. Also, please indent your code.

Comment: Right I will add the other file :) I forgot it totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the PHP script to output its contents as an xml file, and use javascript's XMLHttpRequest function to create a request to the file, and get the information you need.

Comment: I used a small variation of your answer, I just changed the line that changed the link to point into the file select.php to point towards the online file. Thank you very much.